# After upgrading the flutter SDK I was facing the below issue

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies, flutter-upgrade

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSUQH.png)

After upgrading the flutter i was facing an strange issue that are shown in the image I have tried of cleaning and upgrading the dependecies and then tried but same issue is displaying

```
 Error: The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry' because 'BorderRadius?' is nullable and 'BorderRadiusGeometry' isn't.
 'BorderRadius' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
'BorderRadiusGeometry' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
border_radius.dart:1
              borderRadius: _cornerRadiusAnimation.value,
    Error: No named parameter with the name 'isAlwaysShown'.
step_page_scaffold.dart:340
        isAlwaysShown: false,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
scrollbar.dart:87
  const Scrollbar({
```

Comment: Same issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: No, I was not using the latest version

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation

`'isAlwaysShown' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use thumbVisibility instead. This feature was deprecated after v2.9.0-1.0.pre. Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.` 
so instead of using `isAlwaysShown` use `thumbVisibility`,

**So instead of this**

```dart
  isAlwaysShown: false,
```

**use this**

```dart
  thumbVisibility: false,
```